# Android: itemdecoration in recyclerview to be text and only if a certain condition is met

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, item-decoration

I have a recyclerview that shows items that were bought and to be bought. The items are sorted by purchase date which can be in the past and future.

I want to add a separator between the last "past" item and the first "future" one. I know I should add a decorator like the following:

```
DividerItemDecoration decoration = new DividerItemDecoration(Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()), VERTICAL);
rvItems.addItemDecoration(decoration);
```

The decorator is a thin horizontal line that is shown between all items. How can I make the decorator a text, something like "↓ past items ↑ future items" and to be visible only between the relevant items?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In such a case I think it is preferable to have a recycler view adapter that supports multiple types of items.

The `separators` that you call, will be `sections`

Example:

```
sealed class Item {

  data class Section(val sectionText): Item
  data class Purchases(.......): Item

}
```

Adapter:

```
class MyAdapter(private val items: List<Item>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

  companion object {
    const val TYPE_PURCHASES = 0
    const val TYPE_SECTION = 1
  }

  override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
    val type = when (items[position]) {
      is Items.Section -> TYPE_SECTION
      // other types...
      else -> TYPE_PURCHASES
    }
    return type
  }

  override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    val viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder = when (viewType) {
      TYPE_PURCHASES -> {}
      // other view holders...
      else -> {}
    }
    return viewHolder
  }

  override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder?, position: Int) {
     when(holder) {
        is SectionViewHolder -> bindSectionViewHolder(holder)
        is PurchasesViewHolder -> bindSectionViewHolder(holder)
     }
  }

  override fun getItemCount() = items.size
}
```

Then create the corresponding `ViewHolders` for each `type` and instantiate them at  `onCreateViewHolder`.

And when you pass the list of Items in the adapter you should have logic that adds either a Section or an Item to the list.

Similar example from one of my projects:

```
        .subscribeBy(onSuccess = {
            val list = mutableListOf<IViewModel>()
            val previousBookingDate = Calendar.getInstance()
            val bookingDate = Calendar.getInstance()
            it.data?.fold(Date(0)) { previousHeader, bookable ->
                previousBookingDate.time = previousHeader
                bookingDate.time = bookable.getStartDate()
                val timeIgnoringComparator = DateUtils.TimeIgnoringComparator()
                if (timeIgnoringComparator.compare(previousBookingDate, bookingDate) != 0) {
                    list.add(SectionViewModel(bookable.getStartDate(), isDefaultSearch || isDefaultCenterSelected()))
                }
                list.add(BookableItemViewModel(bookable))

                bookable.getStartDate()
            }

            searchResultsLiveData.value = list
        }, onError = {
            isError.setValue(Event(Pair(null, Runnable { performSearch() })))
        })
```

I suggest taking a look at [this](https://github.com/evant/binding-collection-adapter) library to quickly make lists with different item types.

Comment: You wrote "In such a case ", you mean the fact it should be text or the fact it should appear under a certain condition?

Comment: I would say both. Your case refers more to a section rather than a decoration.

Comment: and if I'll need it to be just a line in certain color?

Comment: Then add an item decorator. You can have both.

Comment: How can I do that only under certain condition so it will appear only once between the 2 mentioned items?

Comment: Check this gist: https://gist.github.com/man-trifork/94e287507beb3840b5625ca830556121